# liipimagineBundle bad picture quality

Tags: symfony, thumbnails, liipimaginebundle

I'm using The symfony2 bundle "LiipImagineBundle" to create thumbnails.

It's work fine, exepts for one thing : The quality is very bad and i've seted it to 100(maximum).

How can i have same quality as original picture when i change the size ?

Thanks for your help